# max value of List<List<double []>>

Tags: c#

How to get max value using LINQ

```
List<List<double []>> lists = new List<List<double []>>()
{
    new List<double[]>(){ new double[] { 10, 20 } },
    new List<double[]>(){ new double[] { 30, 40 } }
};
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. And expected results.

Comment: `lists.SelectMany( x => x ).Max()`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to "flatten" the `List<List<>>` into a single collection of arrays, then get the max value of the max value of each array from the list:

```
double max = list.SelectMany(x => x).Max(a => a.Max());
```

Alternatively, you could flatten the entire 3-level collection and get the max of all numbers:

```
double max = list.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y)).Max();
```